# offset array within array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array in this format

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Supplier
        [1] => Supplier Ref
    )
```

I basically need to offset every array with a new field at the beginning, so the outcome should be:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => New Field
        [1] => Supplier
        [2] => Supplier Ref
    )
```

If I can run a loop through each array using for/foreach then that would be great but I'm struggling to find a good method of doing this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) `array_unshift — Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array` -> `$array = array_unshift($array,'New Field');`

Comment: ^^^In context of your loop:  `foreach ($outer_array as &$inner_array) { array_unshift($inner_array, 'New Field'); }` ...note the `&` reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three straightforward ways

1. Use a simple foreach and array_unshift

   ```
   foreach($arr as &$item) {
     array_unshift($item, 'new field');
   }
   ```
2. Use array_walk to apply array_unshift to each array item (will modify the existing array)

   ```
   array_walk($array, function(&$item) { array_unshift($item, 'new field'); });
   ```
3. Use array_map and array_unshift (will return a new array – but the arrays inside the original array will be modified nevertheless)

   ```
   array_map(function(&$item) {
     array_unshift($item, 'new field'); return $item;
   }, $array);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to offset `array` within array `php`. It prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array.